# Setting initial values for new resource in Active Admin

Tags: activeadmin

Does anyone know how to set initial values for new resource in active admin? Should I override some action, write controller for resource or hook to some existing hook?

Comment: You can override new method or update action that follows to the new action (in the top-right corner) with the params, so they will preset all the inputs by default.

Comment: thanks, overriding new in controller section in resource did the job

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can override `DataAccess#build_new_resource`

```
  # Builds a new resource. This method uses the method_for_build provided
  # by Inherited Resources.
  #
  # @returns [ActiveRecord::Base] An un-saved active record base object
  def build_new_resource
    scoped_collection.send(method_for_build, *resource_params)
  end
```

To override do

> ```
> ActiveAdmin.register Order do
>     controller do
>         def build_new_resource
>            r = super
>            r.assign_attributes(name: "new name")
>            r
>         end
>     end 
> end
> ```

Comment: This would be a lot cleaner with `.tap`. ex: super.tap { |resource| resource.assign_attributes(name: "new name") }.  Tap just returns itself at the end of the block, allowing you to mutate the record without having to declare a variable.